# Need to Read From Calendar API Without Publicizing Calendar

Tags: php, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

Thanks for your time.  I've found documentation on how to do this for public calendars, but I need it for a calendar which won't be shared with the world.

This is my code:

```
include( __DIR__ . '/composer/vendor/google/apiclient/autoload.php' ); 

$client_email = 'me@googletokenaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('/home/serverSecret.json');
$scopes = array( Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY );
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials( $client_email, $scopes, $private_key );

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ( $client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired() )
{
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

$client->setApplicationName("A Calendar");
$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarId = 'me@gmail.com';
$params = array( 'singleEvents' => true, 'orderBy' => 'startTime', 'timeMin' => date(DateTime::ATOM), 'maxResults' => 7 );
$events = $cal->events->listEvents($calendarId, $params); 
$calTimeZone = $events->timeZone;
date_default_timezone_set($calTimeZone);

foreach ($events->getItems() as $event)
{
    // Get the timings
    $eventDateStr = $event->start->dateTime;
    if(empty($eventDateStr)) { $eventDateStr = $event->start->date; } // Handle all-day events
    $temp_timezone = $event->start->timeZone;

// Timezone override if applicable
if (!empty($temp_timezone)) { $timezone = new DateTimeZone($temp_timezone); }
else { $timezone = new DateTimeZone($calTimeZone); }

// Set up the timings
$eventdate = new DateTime($eventDateStr,$timezone);
$link = $event->htmlLink;
$TZlink = $link . "&ctz=" . $calTimeZone;
$newmonth = $eventdate->format("M");
$newday = $eventdate->format("j");
?>
<div class="event-container">
    <div class="eventDate">
    <span class="month"><?=$newmonth?></span>
    <br />
    <span class="day"><?=$newday?></span>
    <span class="dayTrail"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="eventBody">
        <a href="<?=$TZlink?>"><?=$event->summary?></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

The above works when I use it with a public calendar using a client key but not when the calendar is made private.  I need to know how to authenticate for private calendars.

Answer (score 0):

You need the OAuth 2.0 service to access the private data:You might need to create a service account:

> Typically, an application uses a service account when the application
>   uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data.
>   For example, an application that uses Google Cloud Datastore for data
>   persistence would use a service account to authenticate its calls to
>   the Google Cloud Datastore API.
>
> https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount